# Is this the correct way to compute tensor bundles of smooth manifolds given by a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by the vanishing locus of a smooth function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. I can compute the cotangent bundle from this embedding by looking at the submanifold of $T^*\mathbb{R}^n$ with vanishing locus $f$, corresponding to the restriction of the tangent bundle, and $df$, corresponding to the compatibility of the differential of 0. The same computation can be given for the tangent bundle by replacing the $dx_i$ coordinates with $\partial_{x_i}$ coordinates. If I want to compute corresponding tensor bundles, does this just amount to looking at the vanishing locus of $0$ tensored by each of the $dx_i$ or $\partial_{x_i}$?

For example, if I look at the two sphere given by $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$, it has the cotangent bundle
$$
\frac{(x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1, 2xdx + 2ydy + 2zdz)}
$$
where I mean the manifold $\mathbb{R}^6$ given by the coordinates on top, cut out by the two equations on the bottom. Then, I'm guessing the tensor bundle would have the presentation
$$
\frac{(x,y,z,dx\otimes dx, dx\otimes dy, dx\otimes dz, dy\otimes dx, dy\otimes dy, dy\otimes dz, dz\otimes dx, dz\otimes dy, dz\otimes dz)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1, (2xdx + 2ydy + 2zdz)\otimes dx_i, dx_i\otimes(2xdx + 2ydy + 2zdz), (2xdx + 2ydy + 2zdz)\otimes(2xdx + 2ydy + 2zdz))}
$$
but the problem is that it's cut out by a lot more equations than what a simple dimension count would yield. What am I missing?